# Extract String from selenium logging from chrome console using selenium

Tags: string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, logging, automated-tests

I am trying to extract a string from the console logs but i cant seem to convert them to a string and extract what i want.

The console logss are appearing in the selenium console using

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging", "true");
    LoggingPreferences logs = new LoggingPreferences();

    logs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
```

But i cant figure out how to extract a specific string for a log.

```
[1639658975.491][DEBUG]: DevTools WebSocket Event: Runtime.consoleAPICalled 
E7C23BCA630CC60FB52E55F95F3A8CAC {
"args": [ {
  "type": "string",
  "value": "OPENING im://launch?iss=http%3A%2F%2FukdM"
```

} ]

Im trying to extract the value here but dont know how to access the log to convert to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're creating the driver:

```java
var options = new ChromeOptions();
    var logging = LoggingPreferences();
        logging.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
    options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.LOGGING_PREFS, logging);

var service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
    // These are different kinds of logs, they're not necessary to get console logs.
    //.withLogLevel(ChromiumDriverLogLevel.INFO)
    //.withLogOutput(System.out)
    .build();

var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options);

driver.manage().window().size = Dimension(1920, 1080);
// Self-check
assertThat(driver.manage().logs().availableLogTypes).contains(LogType.BROWSER);
```

and then later (e.g. at the end of each test in `@AfterEach`):

```java
var logs = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).all;
assertThat(logs).isEmpty();
```